# Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

The problem I need to solve: I am writing a little vue-app based on VueJS3.

I got a lot of different sidebars and I need to prevent the case that more than one sidebar is open at the very same time.

To archive this I am following [this article](https://medium.com/@rmmmsy/creating-a-sidebar-with-dynamic-content-using-vue-and-vuex-88e904894e00).

Now I got a problem:

> Vue received a Component which was made a reactive object. This can lead to unnecessary performance overhead, and should be avoided by marking the component with `markRaw` or using `shallowRef` instead of `ref`. (6)

This is my code:

`SlideOvers.vue`

```html
<template>
    <component :is="component" :component="component" v-if="open"/>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'SlideOvers',
    computed: {
        component() {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent
        },
        open () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

`UserSlideOver.vue`

```html
<template>
    <div>test</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'UserSlideOver',
    components: {},
    computed: {
        open () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen
        },
        component () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

`slideovers.js` (vuex-store)

```js
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

const state = {
    sidebarOpen: false,
    sidebarComponent: null
}

const getters = {
    sidebarOpen: state => state.sidebarOpen,
    sidebarComponent: state => state.sidebarComponent
}

const actions = {
    toggleSidebar ({commit, state}, component) {
        commit (types.TOGGLE_SIDEBAR)
        commit (types.SET_SIDEBAR_COMPONENT, component)
    },
    closeSidebar ({commit, state}, component) {
        commit (types.CLOSE_SIDEBAR)
        commit (types.SET_SIDEBAR_COMPONENT, component)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    [types.TOGGLE_SIDEBAR] (state) {
        state.sidebarOpen = !state.sidebarOpen
    },

    [types.CLOSE_SIDEBAR] (state) {
        state.sidebarOpen = false
    },

    [types.SET_SIDEBAR_COMPONENT] (state, component) {
        state.sidebarComponent = component
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

`App.vue`

```html
<template>
    <SlideOvers/>
    <router-view ref="routerView"/>
</template>

<script>
import SlideOvers from "./SlideOvers";

export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {SlideOvers},
};
</script>
```

And this is how I try to toggle one slideover:

```html
<template>
  <router-link
      v-slot="{ href, navigate }"
      to="/">
    <a :href="href"
       @click="$store.dispatch ('toggleSidebar', userslideover)">
        Test
    </a>
  </router-link>
</template>
<script>
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      userslideover: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
          import('../../UserSlideOver')
      ),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the recommendation of the warning, use [`markRaw`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#markraw) on the value of `usersslideover` to resolve the warning:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userslideover: markRaw(defineAsyncComponent(() => import('../../UserSlideOver.vue') )),
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-reactive-component-def?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMySlideOverLink.vue)

Comment: For new comers, `markDraw` comes also from `import { markRaw } from "vue";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.freeze to get rid of the warning.
If you only use shallowRef f.e., the component will only be mounted once and is not usable in a dynamic component.

```js
<script setup>
import InputField from "src/core/components/InputField.vue";

const inputField = Object.freeze(InputField);

const reactiveComponent = ref(undefined);

setTimeout(function() => {
  reactiveComponent.value = inputField;
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() => {
  reactiveComponent.value = undefined;
}, 5000);

setTimeout(function() => {
  reactiveComponent.value = inputField;
}, 5000);
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="reactiveComponent" />
</template>
```